# How to observe (or intercept) conversation beginning in CDI?

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, conversation-scope

I would like to observe or intercept `Conversation.begin()` method call in CDI in order to stock the new `Conversation.getId()` and list all the opened conversation.

I don't find in the spec ([JSR-299](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/)) how to observe such event. I'm thinking of complex system of [Extension](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#spi) which would perhaps use [`ProcessInjectionTarget`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#pit) or [`ProcessProducer`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#pp) or other events to do that... but I feel like it exists another simpler solution...

Comment: I've marked that question "solved" but it's not really the case as it now depends on the resolution of [CDI-199 feature request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-199)... if anybody has another solution don't hesitate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, these are built in beans and so can't be decorated. In CDI 1.1 you could use ProcessInjectionPoint, or add a request to issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI to be able to decorate built in beans.

So right now, not much idea, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, I've just created [CDI-199 feature request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-199)